# Run the maven build its showing below console error

Tags: maven, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

When i run the maven build it's showing the below error like

[Click here to see the full explanation of this Error](https://community.alfresco.com/message/834781-run-the-maven-build-i-am-getting-below-error)

ERROR [webscripts.connector.RemoteClient] [http-bio-8080-exec-9] Error status 500 Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for DigGovi:solr-config:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin is missing. @ DigGovi:solr-config:[unknown-version], D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\solr-config\pom.xml, line 74, column 29
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Alfresco Repository and Share Quickstart with database and an embedded Tomcat runner.
[INFO] Alfresco Repository AMP Module
[INFO] Alfresco Share AMP Module
[INFO] Alfresco Repository WAR Aggregator
[INFO] Alfresco Solr 4 Configuration
[INFO] Alfresco Share WAR Aggregator
[INFO] Alfresco, Share and Solr4 Tomcat Runner
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Alfresco Repository and Share Quickstart with database and an embedded Tomcat runner. 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ DigGovi ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ DigGovi ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress (compress-js) @ DigGovi ---
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ DigGovi ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\pom.xml to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\DigGovi\1.0-SNAPSHOT\DigGovi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Alfresco Repository AMP Module 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:2.2.0:set-version (default-set-version) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Removed -SNAPSHOT suffix from version - 1.0
[INFO] Added timestamp to version - 1.0.1807091509
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-test-resource (add-env-test-properties) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\src\main\resources
[INFO] Copying 17 resources to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\target/amp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress (compress-js) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] demoamp.js (774b) -> demoamp-min.js (0b)[0%]
[INFO] total input (774b) -> output (0b)[0%]
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:2.2.0:refresh (refresh-webscripts-repo-and-share) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[WARNING] Connection failed to localhost:8080, null webapp refresh aborted
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\target\classes
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\com\sun\pdfview\pdfrenderer\0.9.1-patched\pdfrenderer-0.9.1-patched.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (add-module-properties-to-test-classpath) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to alfresco/module/DigGovi-repo-amp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (add-module-config-to-test-classpath) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\target\test-classes
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\com\sun\pdfview\pdfrenderer\0.9.1-patched\pdfrenderer-0.9.1-patched.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:2.2.0:amp (default-amp) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\target\amp\lib\DigGovi-repo-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Building amp: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\target\DigGovi-repo-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ DigGovi-repo-amp ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\target\DigGovi-repo-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\1.0-SNAPSHOT\DigGovi-repo-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\pom.xml to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\1.0-SNAPSHOT\DigGovi-repo-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Alfresco Share AMP Module 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/): Access denied to http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml. Error code 403, Forbidden
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from http://download.java.net/maven/2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.dev.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/): Access denied to http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml. Error code 403, Forbidden
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:2.2.0:set-version (default-set-version) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Removed -SNAPSHOT suffix from version - 1.0
[INFO] Added timestamp to version - 1.0.1807091510
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 13 resources to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\target/amp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress (compress-js) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] TemplateWidget.js (721b) -> TemplateWidget-min.js (415b)[57%]
[INFO] total input (721b) -> output (415b)[57%]
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:2.2.0:refresh (refresh-webscripts-repo-and-share) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[WARNING] Connection failed to localhost:8080, null webapp refresh aborted
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (add-module-properties-to-test-classpath) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to alfresco/module/DigGovi-share-amp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (add-module-config-to-test-classpath) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\target\test-classes
[INFO] /D:/Selva Kumar G/eclipse_workspace/DigGovi/DigGovi-share-amp/src/test/java/DigGovi/DigGovi/demoamp/po/DemoPage.java: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\src\test\java\DigGovi\DigGovi\demoamp\po\DemoPage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /D:/Selva Kumar G/eclipse_workspace/DigGovi/DigGovi-share-amp/src/test/java/DigGovi/DigGovi/demoamp/po/DemoPage.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:2.2.0:amp (default-amp) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\target\amp\lib\DigGovi-share-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Building amp: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\target\DigGovi-share-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ DigGovi-share-amp ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\target\DigGovi-share-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\1.0-SNAPSHOT\DigGovi-share-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\pom.xml to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\1.0-SNAPSHOT\DigGovi-share-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Alfresco Repository WAR Aggregator 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ repo ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ repo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-resource (add-env-properties) @ repo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ repo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\src\main\amp
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress (compress-js) @ repo ---
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) @ repo ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ repo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ repo ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ repo ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:exploded (prepare-exploded-war) @ repo ---
[INFO] Exploding webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [repo] in [D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id org.alfresco:alfresco]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id DigGovi:DigGovi-repo-amp]
[INFO] Installing into destination folder: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\target\DigGovi-repo-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp into D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [122156 msecs]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- replacer:1.5.3:replace (disable-securecomms) @ repo ---
[INFO] Replacement run on 1 file.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ repo ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [repo] in [D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id org.alfresco:alfresco]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id DigGovi:DigGovi-repo-amp]
[INFO] Installing into destination folder: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-repo-amp\target\DigGovi-repo-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp into D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [15529 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ repo ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\repo\1.0-SNAPSHOT\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\pom.xml to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\repo\1.0-SNAPSHOT\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Alfresco Solr 4 Configuration 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ solr-config ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\solr-config\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ solr-config ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:unpack (unpack-alfresco-config) @ solr-config ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.alfresco:alfresco-solr4:config:5.1.e:zip
[INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\org\alfresco\alfresco-solr4\5.1.e\alfresco-solr4-5.1.e-config.zip to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\alf_data_dev\solr4\config with includes "" and excludes ""
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:regex-property (regexp-property) @ solr-config ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- replacer:1.5.3:replace (setup-solr-config) @ solr-config ---
[INFO] Replacement run on 2 files.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress (compress-js) @ solr-config ---
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ solr-config ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\solr-config\pom.xml to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\solr-config\1.0-SNAPSHOT\solr-config-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Alfresco Share WAR Aggregator 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ share ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ share ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:unpack-dependencies (unpack) @ share ---
[INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\org\alfresco\share\5.1.e\share-5.1.e.war to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\target\dependency with includes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" and excludes ""
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ share ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\src\main\amp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress (compress-js) @ share ---
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) @ share ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ share ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ share ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ share ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ share ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [share] in [D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\target\share-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[info] Copying manifest...
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id org.alfresco:share]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id DigGovi:DigGovi-share-amp]
[INFO] Installing into destination folder: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\target\share-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\DigGovi-share-amp\target\DigGovi-share-amp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp into D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\target\share-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [286340 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\target\share-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ share ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\target\share-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\share\1.0-SNAPSHOT\share-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\pom.xml to C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\DigGovi\share\1.0-SNAPSHOT\share-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Alfresco, Share and Solr4 Tomcat Runner 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ runner ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\runner\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ runner ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress (compress-js) @ runner ---
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (copy-tomcat-resources) @ runner ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (run-wars) > process-classes @ runner >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ runner ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress (compress-js) @ runner ---
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (run-wars) < process-classes @ runner <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (run-wars) @ runner ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\runner\target\tomcat
[INFO] setting SystemProperties:
[INFO]  solr.solr.home=D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi/alf_data_dev/solr4/config
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: 
[INFO] Deploying dependency wars
[INFO] Deploy warfile: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to contextPath: /alfresco
[INFO] Deploy warfile: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\target\share-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to contextPath: /share
[INFO] Deploy warfile: C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\org\alfresco\alfresco-solr4\5.1.e\alfresco-solr4-5.1.e.war to contextPath: /solr4
[INFO] Deploy warfile: C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\org\alfresco\api-explorer\1.0\api-explorer-1.0.war to contextPath: /api-explorer
Jul 09, 2018 3:32:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 09, 2018 3:32:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Jul 09, 2018 3:32:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 09, 2018 3:34:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-07-09 15:34:22,064  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Using database URL 'jdbc:h2:D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi/alf_data_dev/h2_data/alf_dev;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;MVCC=FALSE;LOCK_MODE=0' with user 'alfresco'.
 2018-07-09 15:34:27,588  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Connected to database H2 version 1.4.190 (2015-10-11)
 2018-07-09 15:34:39,387  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
```

Comment: I see this in your log `Caused by: org.springframework.extensions.surf.exception.UserFactoryException: Unable to create user - failed to retrieve user metadata: `. Should this be your root cause of the failure?

Comment: @linc01n  Pls guide me how to resolve it?

Comment: did you check that database created properly?

Comment: @SanjayPatel Am new to this pls guide me to check..........

Comment: Database is mysql or postgres?

Comment: @SanjayPatel Database is Postgresql

Comment: Download any gui tool for postgresql and connect with connection parameter which is defined in alfresco-global.properties

Comment: No @SanjayPatel

Comment: If DB is not created then it will not work

Comment: @SanjayPatel Thank You So much for your Assistance......